# Database structure issue

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Here is the scenario:
There are teachers who teaches various subjects. Subjects comprises of chapters. There may be more than one teacher teaching the same subjects but have different chapters assigned to them. There are topics, subtopics (hierarchical) inside chapters.

I am concerned with the entities: chapters, topics only. Chapters have properties like teacher_id, subject_id,title, designated_hours. Topics (also has subtopics and subtopics may contain  subtopics inside them i.e to say hierarchical). Topic properties are title, teaching_methodology, hours, periods, completion_date.

My proposed structure:

```
chapters                  topics
 -id                       -id
 -subject_id (fk)          -chapter_id (fk) references chapters
 -teacher_id (fk)          -parent_id (fk) references topics itself
 -title                    -title
 -designated_hours         -hours
                           -periods
                           -completion_date
                           -teaching_methodology
```

My question is whether my structure is normalized ? In case when topics have subtopics, the fields like hours, periods, completion_date, teaching_methodology will be null. Should I create separate table for these properties like

```
  topic_properties
   -id
   -topic_id (fk) references topic
   -hours
   -periods
```

You can also propose other database structure. I just want to make sure i get the structure right before i start this module

Comment: Can a chapter have more than one (top-level) topic?

Comment: yes chapter can have more than one top-level topics

Comment: `periods` looks a little fishy. Do you always treat it as a whole? If not (e.g. if it's a comma-separated list of values), you are violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and the 1NF.

Comment: periods is integer, no of periods required to complete that topic

Comment: @PradipChitrakar Got it. One more question: do parent and child topics have to be in the same chapter?

Comment: Well, chapter contains topics, topics contains subtopics and so on. Is that what you are asking ? sorry if i got it wrong

Comment: @PradipChitrakar Is that containment _exclusive_ (so the same topic cannot be contained by two different chapters)? I'm assuming yes, but wanted your confirmation...

Comment: its one to many relation from chapter to topic table. yes you are right same topic cannot belong to two different chapters

Comment: david hay covers this in his book Enterprise Model Patterns, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track here and you don't need the additional table. I'd just make a small adjustment to ensure parent and child topics cannot belong to different chapters:

```
CREATE TABLE chapters (
    chapter_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    -- (other fields)
);

CREATE TABLE topics (
    chapter_id INT,
    topic_no INT,
    parent_topic_no INT,
    -- (other fields)
    PRIMARY KEY (chapter_id, topic_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (chapter_id)
        REFERENCES chapters (chapter_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (chapter_id, parent_topic_no)
        REFERENCES topics (chapter_id, topic_no)
);
```

Note how the second FK forces the child row to have the same `chapter_id` as the parent row.

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/993db/10)